# Empty Dictionaries Using Automapper

Tags: automapper

I am trying to map an `IDictionary<string,object>` to another `IDictionary<string,object>`. The source dictionary contains `int`, `int[]`, `string[]` and strongly-typed lists of domain objects. I wanted to map that dictionary to a dictionary where my domain objects get mapped to DTOs.

I created mappings for the domain objects which maps them to the equivalent DTOs. However, when trying to map the dictionary, it results in an empty `IDictionary<string,object>`.

Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was doing something dumb. The dictionary was being initialized in the constructor of the parent object, tough overwriting Automapper generated dictionary.

Sigh.